# How to move from last view to any view in view controller hierarchies

Tags: view, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Suppopse there are five view as A,B,C,D,E i am presenting view A to B then B to C using present view controller method. Now i want to dismiss view controller form View C to A directly. How we can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this (and perhaps the simplest) would be to use a `UINavigationController` and push `UIViewController`s onto it.

Then you can simply call: `[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Another more complex way to handle this if you really want modal view controllers would be to set up the UIViewControllers with callbacks to register that they should close immediately on next appearance.

```
-(void)closeImmediately
{
    mCloseImmediately = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(mCloseImmediately)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        return;
    }
    // ... other normal setup code
}
```

Doing this in `viewWillAppear` and without animation means that this `UIViewController` never gets displayed.

Comment: no we are not using navigaton controoler. using present view controllers only

Comment: Yes, I understood that from question. I was merely suggesting from your desire for this functionality that perhaps it would be a wise choice to make a change in your design.

I myself have created complex modal UIViewController hierarchies just like those described in your question and my answer is how I solved the problem of how to close them quickly, but I know from experience it can be cumbersome.